# Почему правило времени жизни №2 не применяется к "конструктору" структуры с временем жизни (или любая функции без &self)?

Tags: rust, время-жизни

Допустим, у меня есть вот такая структурка:

```
struct SubstringHolder<'a> {
    substring: &'a str,
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
}
```

Делаю такую функцию, компилируется без ошибок:

```
fn create_substring_holder(original: &str, start: usize, end: usize) -> SubstringHolder {
    SubstringHolder{substring: original, start, end}
}
```

Тут вопросов нет, применяется правило времени жизни и указание времени жизни для `original` не требуется

Но почему в нижеследующем случае требуется напрямую указывать время жизни для `original` (без этого не компилируется):

```
impl<'a> SubstringHolder<'a> {
    fn new(original: &str, start: usize, end: usize) -> Self {
        let mut start_tmp = start;
        let mut end_tmp = end;
        
        if start > end {
            start_tmp = 0;
        }
        
        if end > original.len() {
            end_tmp = original.len();
        }
        
        Self{substring: original, start: start_tmp, end: end_tmp}
    }
}
```

Почему в случает имплементации структуры не применяется правила вывода:

> 2. If there is exactly one input lifetime, that lifetime is assigned to all output lifetimes.

то есть тут один параметр с временем жизни - `original`, и он, по идее, должен автоматически быть применен к возвращаемому значению `Self`. Разве не так?

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы, конечно, видеть сообщение об ошибке. Но могу догадаться, что проблема в original: &str. Компилятор резонно предполагает, что время жизни original может быть меньше, чем Self.
Достаточно будет объявить конструктор

```
fn new(original: &'a str, start: usize, end: usize) -> Self
```

тогда компилятор сможет корректно определить время жизни original.